# How to get value of an input - reac native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-native

I'm trying to get the value of an input after the user click submit, I have a simple form that ask for the user to sign,

when the user click submit, inside the handleLogin, i call the handleSignature and passes the signature to an input, but here is were I'm lost how can I get the value of this field, is the field that contains the signature.led.

```
 export default function Form({navigation}) {
    
    const handleLogin = (data, setSubmitting) => {  
        handleSignature();
    
    
    }

    return (      
        <>
            <Formik   
                initialValues = {{first_name: '', last_name:' }}
                onSubmit = { (values, {setSubmitting }) => { 
                        
            
                    handleLogin(values, setSubmitting);
                
                }}>

                {({handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, isSubmitting, errors, touched}) => ( 
                    
                    <> 
                        <View style={styles.CONTENT}>
                        
                        <View style={styles.INPUTS}>
                                                    
                            <MyTextInput
                                label           = "First Name" 
                                onChangeText    = {handleChange('first_name')}
                                onBlur          = {handleBlur('first_name')}
                                values          = {values.first_name || ''}
                                returnKeyType   = "next"
                                innerRef        = {input1}    
                                
                            />
                            
                            <MyTextInput
                                label           = "Last Name" 
                                onChangeText    = {handleChange('last_name')}
                                onBlur          = {handleBlur('last_name')}
                                values          = {values.last_name}
                                returnKeyType   = "next"
                                refInner        = {input2} 
                            /> 

                            <MyTextInput 
                                values          = {signature} 
                            /> 
                        </View>
                </>
        </Formik>
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want get the values of input you need to bind the value to state, as follows

```
          constructor(props) {
                super(props);

            this.state = {
               first_name: '',  // state
               last_name: ''  
            };
          }


          <MyTextInput
              label="First Name"
              onBlur={handleBlur('first_name')}
              values={values.first_name || ''}
              returnKeyType="next"
              innerRef={input1}
              onChangeText={e => this.setState({first_name: e})} // binding value
            />
```

when you bind the value you can get the value on any function as follows

```
const handleLogin = (data, setSubmitting) => {  
     handleSignature();
     console.log(this.state.first_name) // the value of input
}
```

---

the above metho will be work if you use class component, but in your case you are using functional component so you can solve the problem using below snippts

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
export default function Form({navigation}) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setlastName] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = (data, setSubmitting) => {
    handleSignature();

    console.log(firstName); // output the firstname
    console.log(lastName); // output the lastname
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MyTextInput
        label="First Name"
        onBlur={handleBlur('first_name')}
        values={values.first_name || ''}
        returnKeyType="next"
        innerRef={input1}
        onChangeText={e => setFirstName(e)} // binding value
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sortry for this question Mohamend, but where do I need to declare "this.state" everywhere where I put I get an error "Unexpexted token, expected ",". I have updated the code on my questions. THank you